# How to create web-service using NW AS Java without SAP Gateway?

Tags: java, netweaver

I have a remote access to [SAP AS Java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RaiPU.png) and I want to create and publish Web services using NWDS 7.3 or Eclipse Juno using EJB projects. But I want to create Web services without SAP Gateway or ABAP. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

You **DO NOT** need SAP Gateway to create web-services. 
Here are the steps you need to perform to create WS in AS Java from an existing Java Bean (which should be created in advance):

1. In the Package Explorer select *Web-services >> Create Web Service* in context menu
2. Move [slider](https://blogs.sap.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/5_355387.jpg) to the lowest button *Develop service*
3. Select proper SAP Server
4. Select endpoint if needed. For the first time you can select *No endpoint*
5. Finish.

After you deploy your service it will be visible in [WS Navigator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWXg7.jpg)

Enjoy!

P.S. Detailed manuals are [here](https://blogs.sap.com/2014/01/03/creating-webservice-using-sap-nwds/) and [here](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw73/helpdata/en/4b/7526c212fc41a8e10000000a421937/content.htm).

Answer (score 0):

NW 7.3+ supports JEE 5 web services.  Use @WebService, @WebMethod, etc. on your classes, pack them in a war, and deploy.